# Embedded Signing In Web Application

Tags: docusignapi

We are planning to go paper-less using embedded signing using RestFul API,
Here is our scenario,

Application has users with different roles, for example, Officer, Manager, Customer all have login access to system.

We have .docx document that requires all three users to sign, first Customer, then Manager and in the last Officer.
I am following this [link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded)

My Questions are,

- Does embedded signing allows adding multiple recipients
- When One user (Customer) signs the document where does signed document will go? how can we access it and how the Second user (Manager) will get that document to sign which is signed by Customer
- How can I retrieve the document back in my Web Application when all users have signed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does embedded signing allows adding multiple recipients

Yes, it does. You can embed some and have others remote (via email) or you can have them all embedded. Very flexible.

> When One user (Customer) signs the document where does signed document
> will go?

The document is not complete/signed until ALL recipients acted on it. In the case of signers, they all need to sign. When they are all done, the document is stored in the DocuSign Cloud, but can be emailed, downloaded etc. as you choose.

> how can we access it and how the Second user (Manager) will get that
> document to sign which is signed by Customer

Various ways, you can design your app to download it, you can have it emailed to the manager, or you can have the manager go to the web app or go to your app where it's available. Very flexible.

> How can I retrieve the document back in my Web Application when all
> users have signed it.

You can use a DocuSign connect webhook that will send you notification when the document is ready and even send you the document itself. You can also retrieve it via the API when you choose to do so.